# VB.Net Highlighted Text Event Handler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, highlighting, selectedtext

I'm working with a Rich Textbox and want to get the text that the user will be highlighting with the mouse.  Is there an event handler in VB.net that does this?

Comment: It was for a WinForm but it got answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is RichTextBox.SelectionChanged event.

You can use it like that:

```
Private Sub r1_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles r1.SelectionChanged
    Me.Text = r1.SelectedText
End Sub
```